# getting attributes in simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Below is the function which i am using to convert xml to array

```
$xml    =   '<xml><CodeshareInfo OperatingCarrier="EY" OperatingFlightNumber="269">ETIHAD AIRWAYS</CodeshareInfo></xml>';
$obj        =   simplexml_load_string($xml); // Parse XML
$obj->registerXPathNamespace("soap", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
$array      =   json_decode(json_encode($obj), true); // Convert to array
```

when i try with the parent node "xml"

```
<xml><CodeshareInfo OperatingCarrier="EY" OperatingFlightNumber="269">ETIHAD AIRWAYS</CodeshareInfo></xml>
```

i get this result

```
Array
(
    [CodeshareInfo] => ETIHAD AIRWAYS
)
```

but if i try without parent node "xml"

```
<CodeshareInfo OperatingCarrier="EY" OperatingFlightNumber="269">ETIHAD AIRWAYS</CodeshareInfo>
```

i can get the attributes and the value

```
Array
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [OperatingCarrier] => EY
            [OperatingFlightNumber] => 269
        )
    [0] => ETIHAD AIRWAYS
)
```

what should i change in code to get the output with attributes and values as my xml data is from a soap request and once i receive i will convert as array to access its value and attributes.

Comment: Couldn't you just iterate though the `$obj`?

Comment: well if it is a few lines of xml then i would have done that... but what i am passing to simplexml object is a big xml file which is getting generated on request... Let me tell you clearly on what i am working.. its a travel portal where i am getting the flights availability through soap request as xml which i pass it to simplexml_load_string and convert it to array.. and what i have mentioned in my xml is a piece of string from that huge xml and this is the place i cant get the attributes instead i get only the values...

Comment: Small or large you should be able to iterate through. I'll provide a sample given your sample of what I mean..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the provided XML you can iterate through it and pull out the attributes and values.

```
<?php
$xml    =   '<xml><CodeshareInfo OperatingCarrier="EY" OperatingFlightNumber="269">ETIHAD AIRWAYS</CodeshareInfo></xml>';
$obj        =   simplexml_load_string($xml); // Parse XML
$obj->registerXPathNamespace("soap", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
foreach($obj as $ob) {
    echo $ob['OperatingCarrier'] . "\n";
    echo $ob . "\n";
    echo $ob['OperatingFlightNumber'] . "\n";
}
```

Output:

> EY
>   ETIHAD AIRWAYS
>   269

Comment: thank you very much... its working... i think something wrong with this line where i am converthing the $obj to array... `$array = json_decode(json_encode($obj), true);`